# How can I figure out which virtualization solution is being used on my commercial VM?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, central-processing-unit

I have a linux VM on a popular VM provider. How can I figure out how it's implemented?

In particular I want to figure out "If the Hypervisor is simulating 4 processors in 1 thread on the physical processor … or if the Hypervisor is passing through 4 physical cores to th VM".*

- [Is the # of CPUs on a virtual machine always meaningful?](https://serverfault.com/questions/179973/is-the-of-cpus-on-a-virtual-machine-always-meaningful)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried asking your provider?

Otherwise a possible "hint" may be if there is a short list of "recommended/preferred" supported OSes. If so and they are short-listed around some of the more contemporary OSes, then chances are good that the hypervisor is possibly Xen-based - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access you could try dmidecode

Some hardware information might give you a clue as has been said.

Answer (score 0):

I would poke around the proc file system, check dmesg and lspci for what devices are installed. Most of the Hypervisors have their name in the device description i.e. VMWare fast ethernet controller.

If you're running windows, check the device manager.

Comment: That's if the OS is pre-installed by the provider with the "helper" applications/drivers installed.

Comment: @user48838 I'd hope so, otherwise you'd be getting a giant performance hit ... if the provider doesn't intall the tools apps, then you need a new provider

Comment: "Enlightened" OSes do not require additional utilities for Zen, not sure about drivers...